# How to use modalDialog to display pop-up which can work in all browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just tried to create pop-up window but its parent window get active while pop-up is still open , in Chome.
    My code is as blow

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function showModalWindow() {
 window.showModalDialog('URL, "Sample.jpg", "resizable: yes");
    }
</script>

how to make this code browser specific.
```

Comment: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.showModalDialog is part part of standard specification yet which is now been used in HTML5. So it has been ignored in chrome. Use jQuery dialog which has the mask and many other features. Go through this [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can add modal:true to the options when calling jQuery dialog()

Comment: Thanks @merlinbeard but  Stil parent winow is active while pop-up is in open mode.